# problem of changing the speed of rotation between two figures in a CANVAS

Tags: javascript, animation

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canva');
let ctx =canvas.getContext('2d');
let img=new Image();
img.src='photorefaite/terre1.png';
let img2=new Image();
img2.src='photorefaite/mercure1.jpg';

ctx.translate(800,400);

function terre(){
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

  ctx.rotate(1*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,50,50);

  ctx.rotate(5*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(img2,50,50,40,40);
 

  ctx.rotate(10*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(img2,100,100,40,40);
  requestAnimationFrame(terre);
}



terre();
```

In the code above I created three images with three different rotational speeds. However the three figures have the same speed of rotation which is "ctx.rotate (10 * Math.PI / 180);", I would like to know how to make so that each image has its own speed of rotation.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your previous question on this code?

Comment: not really, i am waiting for help :)